# How to model this with JPA?

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa, data-modeling

I want to model a couple of object relations and I'm currently not sure about a smart way to do this. Let's assume a `Record` has a OneToMany relationship to different RecordSources. The common attributes of the `RecordSources` are `long id` and `boolean preferred`. Other attributes are individual and the number of record sources may increase in the future.

One possibility is for `Record`

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="record")
private List<GenericSimpleRecordSource> recordSources;
```

where `GenericSimpleRecordSource` would look like this:

```
@Entity
public class GenericSimpleRecordSource implements Serializable
{
    public static enum Type {a,b}

    @ManyToOne private Record record;

    @NotNull
    private Type sourceType;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="source")
    private SimpleRecordSourceA sourceA;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="source")
    private SimpleRecordSourceB sourceB;
}
```

`SimpleRecordSourceA` and `SimpleRecordSourceA` are individual `@Entity` classes. I don't feel comfortable with this approach, using inheritance might be better:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
@DiscriminatorValue("generic")
public class GenericRecordSource
{
   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) private long id;
   @ManyToOne private Record record;
   private boolean preferred;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
public class RecordSourceA extends GenericRecordSource
{
  ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class RecordSourceB extends GenericRecordSource
{
  ...
}
```

This seems to be smarter, but are there any shortcomings using Inheritance? I appreciate any comments on both approaches or even another alternative.

Is it possible to model the `@OneToMany` relationship from `Record` like this?

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="record")
private List<GenericRecordSource> recordSources;
```

Comment: Addressing the last part... The @OneToMany should work as you have it assuming the relationship is based off of a field/column definied in GenericRecordSource. You have a `long id` so it should work.